# Valid frame of reference?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

If the frame of reference moves with the same velocity as the velocity of the object being examined within it, is it truly a frame of reference?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, and one that is often useful. It is the object's rest frame.

For example, you are an object. In your rest frame, you can most easily measure the velocity of another object.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the object isn't moving at constant velocity, then its rest frame won't be inertial.

Comment: I don't know, I might have some difficulty taking measurements while in freefall.

Comment: @aschepler I usually have a lot of difficulties doing physics while in freefall, specially in vacuum in a frictionless environment. However, it's often useful to consider it.